# /odom stops sending tf data

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, node, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problems with my own robot driver because after some time it stops sending odometry data. I checked the tf_monitor and I can see how the net_delay is slowly increasing until I can see the following error:

```
RESULTS: for /base_link to /map
Chain is: /base_link -> /odom -> /map
Net delay     avg = 6.87636: max = 7.88385

Frames:
Frame: /base_link published by /auriga_robot_base Average Delay: -1.96377 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /odom published by /slam_gmapping Average Delay: -2.00705 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: /auriga_robot_base 10.0101 Hz, Average Delay: -1.96377 Max Delay: 0
Node: /laser_broadcaster 19.9809 Hz, Average Delay: -2.05722 Max Delay: 0
Node: /slam_gmapping 20.0302 Hz, Average Delay: -2.00705 Max Delay: 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::ConnectivityException'
  what():  Could not find a common time /map and /base_link.
```

And the net_delay between /base_link and /odom is:

```
RESULTS: for /base_link to /odom
Chain is: /base_link -> /odom
Net delay     avg = 185.881: max = 186.893

Frames:
Frame: /base_link published by /auriga_robot_base Average Delay: 0.00108199 Max Delay: 0.0427322
Frame: /odom published by /slam_gmapping Average Delay: -0.0422399 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: /auriga_robot_base 10.0099 Hz, Average Delay: 0.00108199 Max Delay: 0.0427322
Node: /laser_broadcaster 19.9936 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0931322 Max Delay: 0
Node: /slam_gmapping 20.0204 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0422399 Max Delay: 0
```

I have been also checking my robot's node and the only suspicious thing i saw was:

```
[DEBUG] Socket 15 closed with (ERR|HUP|NVAL) events 24: Broken pipe
```

Any clue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9892//odom-stops-sending-tf-data/) by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-05-05**:
Hi Eric. Only rviz is running in a separate PC. I tested the net delay between /base_link and /odom and it is also increasing slowly but it doesn't send any exception.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-04**:
Is this all running on the same computer? Do you get the same net delay behavior when checking between /base_link and /odom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answer myself. I fixed just updating the odometry information slowier. It was a hardware requirement.

---

Originally posted by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) with karma: 77 on 2011-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0